# SASS | @for and @each loop printing values from a list issues

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I'm using `sass` to print values from a list with a @each and @for loop but when ever i try to print one by one and compile that gathered values in the `css` it takes all the values in the list even using a `nth('', $n)` function.
I'm using the following `code` and `gulp` as my task runner.

```css
// SASS CODE
$btn-default: darken(#DDD, 5%);
$btn-alert: red;
$btn-class: "btn-default", "btn-alert";
$btn-color: $btn-default, $btn-alert;

@each $btn in $btn-class {
    .#{unquote($btn)} {
        @for $i from 1 through length($btn-color) {
            background-color: nth($btn-color, $i);
        }
    }
}


/* CSS CODE : OUTPUT */
.btn-default {
  background-color: #d0d0d0;
  background-color: red; }

.btn-alert {
  background-color: #d0d0d0;
  background-color: red; }
```

I'm a little bit stuck in a project i tried from different ways in the `sass` and when i don't get the values it just return an error instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of introducing an inner `@for` loop that will inevitably render two properties in each ruleset, try using a single loop:

```
@for $i from 1 through length($btn-class) {
  #{nth($btn-class, $i)} {
    background-color: nth($btn-color, $i)
  }
}
```

In the long run however, I would recommend using maps instead. This way you have a clear association between class names and colors which will avoid potential mistakes in larger lists of elements:

```
$buttons: (
  btn-default: $btn-default,
  btn-alert: $btn-alert
);

@each $class, $color in $buttons {
  .#{$class} {
    background-color: $color;
  }
}
```